# Working with NfcAdapter and IsoDep

Tags: android, nfc

I'm trying to send APDUs to a Tag (smartcard) using the IsoDep and the NfcAdapter classes, and I have 2 questions:

1) Is there a way to get Disconnected intents (e.g. when the card is taken away)? I didnt see any predefined intents for such actions. Is the only way to know when a Tag gets disconnected is to poll its IsoDep.isConnected() method?

2) Assuming I need to send more than one APDU in a sequence, is there a way to ensure that no other application interrupts the communication in the middle? Is there something like pcsc transactions (SCardBegin/EndTransaction) with NFC?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Answer to question 1: disconnection of a tag will not generate any intent. You will get a TagLostException (a special kind of IOException) when a tag you are communicating with has disappeared (i.e. does not answer). `IsoDep.isConnected()` merely reports the last known state, so polling it does not generally tell you whether the tag is actually still there.

Answer to question 2: Only the Activity that received the Intent with the tag handle can communicate with the tag. So it is not possible for another Activity or Service to break into or take over the communication with the tag. The only thing that can always happen is that your Activity is suspended (`Activity.onPause()` is called) while your are communicating.